# AJAX Read more posts in wordpress

Tags: ajax

I want an Ajax "read more" button functionality in WordPress.

Here is my attempt, but the code has a bug:

The Code in my functions.php

```
wp_localize_script( 'gershman-script', 'ajax_posts', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'gershman'),
));



function more_post_ajax(){

    $ppp = (isset($_POST["ppp"])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 3;
    $page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;

    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $args = array(
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'cat' => 1,
        'paged'    => $page,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    $out = '';

    if ($loop -> have_posts()) :  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();
        $out .= '<div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
                <h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1>
                <p>'.get_the_content().'</p>
         </div>';

         $out .= '<article id="section__blog--main--post" class="clearfix equal-height" data-group-by="2" '  . $category_string . '">';
            $out .= '<aside class="column" >';
                $out .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
                    $out .= '<figure>';
                        $out .= (has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'image-660-240') : '');
                        $out .= '<span class="meta--stamp">' . get_the_time('F j, Y') . '</span>';
                        $out .= '<h4 class="caps header-blog text-left"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4>';
                    $out .= '</figure>';
                $out .= '</a>';
            $out .= '</aside>';
            $out .= '<aside id="section__blog--meta" class="column">';

                $out .= '<p class="text-left">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>';
                $out .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="caps read--more">Read Now <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right color-green"></i></a>';
            $out .= '</aside>';
        $out .= '</article>';



    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die($out);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

The code in footer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var ppp = 3; // Post per page
            var cat = 1;
            var pageNumber = 1;


            function load_posts(){
                pageNumber++;
                var str = '&cat=' + cat + '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber + '&ppp=' + ppp + '&action=more_post_ajax';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    url: ajax_posts.ajaxurl,
                    data: str,
                    success: function(data){
                        var $data = $(data);
                        if($data.length){
                            $("#ajax-posts").append($data);
                            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
                        } else{
                            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true);
                        }
                    },
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
                    }

                });
                return false;
            }

            $("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
                $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
                load_posts();
            });     

        })
</script>
```

The template page code is

```
<div id="ajax-posts">
  <?php
        $this_post = $post->ID;

        $postsPerPage = 3;

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage, 
            'order' => 'DESC', 
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'cat' => 1
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        $total_posts = $loop->post_count;

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        $display_posts .= '<article id="section__blog--main--post" class="clearfix equal-height" data-group-by="2" '  . $category_string . '">';
            $display_posts .= '<aside class="column" >';
                $display_posts .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
                    $display_posts .= '<figure>';
                        $display_posts .= (has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'image-660-240') : '');
                        $display_posts .= '<span class="meta--stamp">' . get_the_time('F j, Y') . '</span>';
                        $display_posts .= '<h4 class="caps header-blog text-left"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4>';
                    $display_posts .= '</figure>';
                $display_posts .= '</a>';
            $display_posts .= '</aside>';
            $display_posts .= '<aside id="section__blog--meta" class="column">';

                $display_posts .= '<p class="text-left">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>';
                $display_posts .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="caps read--more">Read Now <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right color-green"></i></a>';
            $display_posts .= '</aside>';
        $display_posts .= '</article>';

        $counter++;

        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
  `<section id="section__blog--main">
    <div class="wrapper" id="section__filtered--list">
      <?=$display_posts ?>
      <button id="more_posts" class="button faded" data-nonce="<?=wp_create_nonce("load_news_nonce")?>" data-current-total="3" data-total-posts="<?=$total_posts?>">Load More</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've told you on my blog, about dozen times, you lack localization object.

You've put

```
wp_localize_script( 'gershman-script', 'ajax_posts', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'gershman'),
));
```

But then you place your JavaScript in footer. Put your JavaScript code in a file where your other JavaScript is, or create a new one called `custom.js` and enqueue it like this in your `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'frontend_enqueued_scripts' );

function frontend_enqueued_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'gershman-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'gershman-script', 'ajax_posts', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'gershman'),
    ));
}
```

Or just look where your frontend scripts are enqueued (look for `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook), and place `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_localize_script` inside that function.

Your AJAX call doesn't happen, because you have no `ajax_posts` object present on your page.

Remove the script from footer either in a separate .js file, or in an existing one that is already enqueued inside `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.